# AWS EC2 Instances with Load Balancing during very high traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

Our website is available throughout the year, and can handle traffic quite well with an AWS EC2 medium instance type. Every now and then (once a month), we get really heavy traffic though, and might need several extra large instances. We know when this will occur, and so we can start up instances in advance.

I have just noticed that we would save quite a bit of money when pre-purchasing a medium reserved instance, compared to our current on-demand instance. The problem is that such a reserved instance would mean that our master will be fixed at a medium instance type.

My question is this: Would there be any issues having such a small master, when we need to start-up new x-large slaves? What advantages would there be to keeping the master as an on-demand instance?

Comment: You can try spot instances

Answer (score 0):

Reserved instances are there to save money for those instances you regularly run. I would suggest using reserved instances for your 'master'. The only advantage of keeping that one on-demand is the advantage that you could scale up or down as soon as your constant flow of traffic changes up or down. Make sure you choose the right use for your reserved instance; an 'always-on reserved instance' should have an heavy-use reserved purchase. Those 'peak instances' do best as an on-demand instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have a reservation does not mean you need to be running it all the time. The reservation will apply to any instance matching its parameters.

There are different reservation options as well depending how heavily you use a given instance type. You can take advantage of reserved instances and continue to do what you are doing, you don't need to switch anything.